# Работа скрипта в фоне

Tags: php

Добрый день уважаемые форумчане! Есть вопрос, вот код :

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(1);
#
while (!file_exists('./stop_script.txt')) {
    while (!file_exists('./work.txt')) {
        sleep(5);
    }
    /*
    код, который должен выполнится в рабочем режиме(когда файл work.txt появится)
    */
    unlink('./work.txt');
}
?>
```

И сразу собственно вопрос :
Строчка : sleep(5);
sleep - как я понимаю, останавливает работу скрипта "впадает в сон" на заданное количество секунд(сейчас на 5), а по истечению этого времени работа скрипта продолжается.
Возможно, мой вопрос получится немного глуповат, но лучше спросить и по краснеть немного, чем потом ошибиться.
Если функцией sleep() "усыпить" скрипт на 60 секунд - 1 минуту, то в течении этого времени будут ли использоваться ресурсы системы, или же большая часть ресурсов будет освобождена, и использоваться начнёт по окончанию "сна".
Лучше сформулирую вопрос по другому, если запустить 10 скриптов практически одновременно, где sleep остановит их работу на 1 минуту, мой комп "встанет" или всё будет в порядке как и до запуска этих скриптов?

Comment: Возможно следует побеспокоиться о количестве mysql-соединений. Не уверен в этом, просто видел не раз, что их число сильно ограниченно на всех хостингах и т.о. если 20 раз этот скрипт запустить, то появиться возможность отказа 21-му человеку с ошибкой 500 при коннекте к БД. Но в приведённом коде mysql не видно, так что это просто так, инфа на будущее.

Comment: спасибо, этот момент будет использоваться для создания индексатора сайтов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во время "сна" тратится только память, ЦПУ практически нет.

Комп может встать из-за работы скрипта, но не из-за sleep.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо